# Get meta information, title and all images of any webpage using php

Tags: php, metadata

I want to get all the meta information like description, title, keyword etc of any web page using php.

I am using `get_meta_tags` php function but its displaying warning. I have paste the error below.

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in filename......

And how could i get all images on the web page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"getaddrinfo failed" suggests that your webserver's dns client isn't configured properly. Thererfore php cannot resolve "google.com" to an actual ip address.

Comment: Yes my code working for local url very fine. But not for the actual url.
So want to do in this situation.??

Comment: This depends on the os (maybe also the distribution) and the dns client you're using.

Comment: i am also not able to ping google from command prompt.
Its displaying Destination Host unreachable... :-(

Comment: Most likely the same problem. Which operating system does your webserver use and how is this box connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're putting an address as link identifier (`http://path/to/your/file.php`)? And not a file (`file.php`)?